# Find the running cost of the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

I am unable to solve the following recurrence

```
T(n) = 3T(n/5) + lg^2 n
```

my work:
applying master theorem

```
 a=3 b=5

 n^log5^3n= n^log^0.65
```

this leads to `n^0=1` this isn't comparable with l`og^2n`

I tried with recursion tree as well but it got too complicated. Please help.

Comment: What happened to the n in the exponent?

Answer (score 2):

**T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)**
Here,

> a = 3
>     b = 5
>     f(n) = (lg(n))^2

Now, according to the first case of Master's Theorem,

> If f(n) = O(n^logb(a−e)) for some constant e > 0, then T(n) = Θ(n^logb(a)).

Let us take **e = 3-sqrt(5)**
Therefore, n^logb(a−e) = n^log5(3-(3-sqrt(5))) = n^log5(sqrt(5)) = n^0.5 = sqrt(n).

So, we now have to compare **(lg(n))^2** and **sqrt(n)**.
If we plot the [graphs of these two functions](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=log%28x%29*log%28x%29&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=sqrt%28x%29&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=0&x_max=100&y_min=0&y_max=100&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=3000&image_h=3000), we can clearly observe that **(lg(n))^2 = O(sqrt(n))**.

Since f(n) = O(n^logb(a−e)) for b = 5, a = 3 and e = 3-sqrt(5),
T(n) = Θ(n^logb(a))

=> **T(n) = Θ(n^0.68)**